# SQL Counting rows with columns that satisfy a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table with columns ID and Content populated with data.

```
ID | Content
1  | a
1  | b
1  | c
2  | b
2  | a
3  | b
```

I want to find every ID that has at least one of each 'a', 'b', and 'c' so the returned table would be :

```
ID | Content
1  | a
1  | b
1  | c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using conditional `SUM` validate if inside the `group id` exist 1 or more of each element.

Then select `DISTINCT ID, Content` to eliminate possible duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Content
From YourTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM YourTable
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING SUM(case when Content = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
                AND SUM(case when Content = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
                AND SUM(case when Content = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
            )
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume `SUM(case when Content = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) > 1` should be = 1 or > 0?

Comment: @CuriousCat Dont know your table so not sure if `ID=1` can have duplicated.`a` Should be `=1 ` or  `>=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
where 
Select ID ,SUM(case when Content = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as sum_a ,UM(case when Content = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) as sum_b,
SUM(case when Content = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) as sum_c
             FROM table 
             Group by  ID)x
             where x.sum_a >1 or sum_b>1 or sum_c>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that checks for a certain number of distinct "content" items per ID. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f444ea/8) is a link to an SQL Fiddle for this solution.

```
select 
    id, 
    count(distinct(content)) 
  from tableX 
 group by id 
 having count(distinct(content)) = 3;
```

Comment: This also can work if `content` only have values `a,b,c` if content also allow `a,b,c,d,e,f`  doesnt.